# Import subroutine code into FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I have a small batch file designed to read file names from a folder containing audio tracks and output them into a playlist. The program works well enough, but I had trouble getting the "write track names" code into the FOR loop -- I had to leave it as a subroutine or the batch file would exited prematurely. Is there any way to move those three lines into the FOR loop?

```
@echo off
%~d1
cd %1
for %%* in (.) do set FOLDER="%%~nx*"
set PLAYLIST=%FOLDER%.m3u
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b *.flac *.mp3') do (
  call :WRITE_TRACK_NAMES "%%g"
  )
goto :CHECKOUT
:WRITE_TRACK_NAMES
  set "TRACK=%~nx1"
  echo %TRACK%  >> %PLAYLIST%
  goto :EOF
:CHECKOUT
  exit /b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

@rem Change drive and path.
cd /d %1

for /d %%A in (.) do set "FOLDER=%%~nxA"

@rem If in drive root, . is returned.
if "%FOLDER%" == "." exit /b 1

@rem Create m3u file or erase m3u file content.
2> "%FOLDER%.m3u" echo.

@rem Find and sort audio files and add filename to m3u file.
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b *.flac *.mp3 ^| sort') do >> "%FOLDER%.m3u" echo(%%~nxA

exit /b
```

- Use `setlocal` to prevent the `cd` and variables affecting the global scope of the CMD process.
- Using `/d` argument with `cd` allows switching drive when changing the path.
- Using `sort` as you are using more then 1 file pattern with the `dir` command.
- Advise not using `%%*` as a `for` variable name as `%*` is all arguments of the script or called label.
- Removed `PLAYLIST` name as has no good use.
- Create or erase m3u file to prevent duplicating filenames with appending writes.

Comment: Whoa.  In 30 years of writing (admittedly rudimentary) batch files I hadn't come across the "/d" switch for changing drive and directory simultaneously.  That will help me a lot going forward in the future.  Everything else makes perfect sense, though I wanted to ask if there needs to be a closing paren at the end of the last FOR loop.

Comment: You must mean another pair of parentheses, no need. The interpreter understands that what is after `do` is only one statement. If it were 2 statements then you may need to brace the 1st statement. Oh, you mean `echo(...`, similar to `echo.`, so no `)`.

Comment: No need to use sort, dir can handle that alone `dir /on /b *.flac *.mp3`. And no need to create the m3u file separately, besides that it is extremely inefficient to open and close the m3u file on each iteration of `FOR` command. The two lines can be combined into one single line in a more efficient form: `(for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /on /b /a-d *.flac *.mp3') do echo=%%~nxA)>"%FOLDER%.m3u"` I replaced `echo(` by `echo=` to avoid the confusion by the extra parentheses that I added. `echo(` is useful to protect against `/?` which simply can't happen with file names.